# How can i store String values in hashmap rather than array?

Tags: java, string, hashmap

Here i have string ,further i need to store String values in hash map for sotring,could anybody guide me.thanks for your help.

```
values="w,l,j,l,m,n";
String values = request.getParameter("values");
```

Comment: why you need hash map to sort values. You could do more efficiently using array

Comment: according to my requirement,i'm using,please guide me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use directly

```
Arrays.sort(resultarray);

//if you require hash map only then
Map<Integer, String> source = new HashMap<Integer,String>();
for(int i=1;i<=resultarray.length;i++){
 source.put(i,resultarray[i]);
}
```

I think this should be good.

Comment: without array using hashmap how can i do it?